# The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition and created simple Asp.net5 application. When I try to debug I'm getting this error.

```
The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details
```

Here are my project settings:

```
Solution DNX SDK Version : 1.0.0-beta5,
Platform : .NET Core
Architecture : x64
```

(Tried with x86 as well)

Also followed the steps mentioned in [this link](http://www.sblackler.net/2015/05/02/Up-And-Running-With-DNX-DNVM-DNU/) but they didn't help.

Tried reinstalling VS2015 as well, but no luck. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Run it from the NuGet console (in VS 2015: `Tools` > `NuGet Package Manager` > `Package Manager Console`)

```
dnvm upgrade
dnvm upgrade -r CoreClr
```

Comment: I tried it victor, getting the same error. did system restart as well. Able to see the latest version. Still no luck.

Comment: I got installed Win7 from scratch with PowerShell v4, VS 2015 Enterprise Edition and got this error. This helped for me. Thanks!

Comment: I created new project and copied the old files. After following steps mentioned in my link and finally these 2 steps helped me fixed this issue.

Comment: Can this be run inside VS2015 somehow?

Comment: Yes, run it from the NuGet console

Comment: Could you point us to any documentation explaining what's going on with these commands?

Comment: When running the last command I just get `A positional parameter could not be found that accepts 'CoreClr'.

Comment: The solution is to use the .NET Version Manager (dnvm) command line tool to install the correct version of framework.  My problem was that I had rc1 installed on my machine, but the online project templates still used beta5.  This article describes how to install frameworks using the command line:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005145/DNVM-DNX-and-DNU-Understanding-the-ASP-NET-Runtime

Comment: I had the same problem and it fixed after updating the version number in global.json. Thanks @TimothyKlenke

Comment: Ran both but still got the error. After restarting Visual Studio the solution built successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I got this error when I selected the Class Library (Package) project type from the **Templates > Visual Studio C# > Web** template structure (see image).

[image: Class Library in Web template folder]

What I really wanted was the "Class Library" which has the description "A project for creating a C# class library (.dll)".  When I created a new project under this type, I did not get this error.

Comment: This is actually where I get the error, if I select that project type in VS 2015

Comment: I did the same thing but for Console Application (Package)...Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Found the solution at last !,

First run the command,

**dnvm upgrade**

if this command fails, with errors like the process is being used, run it again. And it will work after a few tries, i think the lock is due to some retires VS is doing to install the DNU properly. After this command run,

**dnvm upgrade -r CoreClr**

this command should restore your Core packages. It worked for me on some projects.

*But if even after this the project is showing the same error, then close Visual Studio, reopen it and you will notice that the references are not loading. And it will ask your to look at the error list, which is good as once you look at the 35 odd errors, one of them give you a command to run, Run this command,*

**dnu restore**

These three commands should get your project building.

Comment: doesn't work for me.. unclear. possibly DNVM runs into errors but I'm about to give up... :(

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is the same as a known issue and relates to not having the correct version of power shell installed.  You can see the solution that helped me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546274/how-to-fix-dnx-dnvm-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 3):

I tried accepted answer but no avail.
I solved by typing below script in command prompt.

```
dnvm install 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -f
```

And I reloaded project and the problem solved.

Comment: Need restart visual studio 2015 after `dnvm install`

Answer (score 0):

I have met with same issue and here I found the solution.To begin with you need an internet connection and visit the this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1039152/DNX-SDK-Version-dnx-clr-win-x-beta-Failedto

First of all,you need to set the path in Environment Variables for Powershell
, example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Windows PowerShell\1.0
```

And then enter the following comments mentioned in the website..in Command Prompt(cmd.exe).

Answer (score 0):

You need to update powershell tools for vs.

Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Visual Studio Gallery -> PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2015