# Build ASP.NET 5 project with Jenkins, cannot find dnx runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, jenkins

I have a problem with building ASP.NET 5 in Jenkins. The error message is as follow:

```
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 1/03/2016 12:14:47 PM.
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TestWebsite\workspace\TestWebsite.sln" on node 1 (Rebuild target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TestWebsite\workspace\TestWebsite.sln" (1) is building "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TestWebsite\workspace\src\TestWebsite\TestWebsite.xproj" (2) on node 1 (Rebuild target(s)).
GetRuntimeToolingPathTarget:
Cannot find DNX runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1 in the folder: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\runtimes
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets(126,5): error : The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TestWebsite\workspace\src\TestWebsite\TestWebsite.xproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TestWebsite\workspace\src\TestWebsite\TestWebsite.xproj" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TestWebsite\workspace\TestWebsite.sln" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

I tried the method in [The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957824/the-dnx-runtime-package-needs-to-be-installed-see-output-window-for-more-detail), but could not solve the problem.

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile>dnvm list

Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
   1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win
  *1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win             default
   1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
   1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win
```

I install Jenkins in the same machine where the Visual Studio 2015 is installed. I tried a Console application and it could be compiled and tested in Jenkins.

I found that the Dnx runtimes are under C:\Users\.dnx\runtims\ folder, rather than C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\runtimes. Actually, there is no .dnx\runtimes in folder systemprofile. I tried to delete all the runtion in C:\Users\.dnx\runtims\ and then run dnvm update to reinstall the runtimes. However, nothing special happened. All the runtimes were install to C:\Users\.dnx\runtims\ again. Is there any way to direct the runtime path to C:\Users\.dnx\runtims\?

Can anyone help to see how to solve the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by changing the login user. I right clicked Jenkins in Services and select Property. Then in Log On tag, set this account to a user with admin privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Just an add to Ben's answer, I met the same problem, and tried Ben's solution by changing the log on account of jenkins services, it works , only after I restart my jenkins machine. I don't know why, but still leave my comments here in case any one encounter the same problem with me and it may save his/her time.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: That's true, I tried to add comments but I have no enough reputation to do that:(

Comment: Thank you Emma for this valuable comment.