# New Class Library (Package) project has no assembly references to .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Creating a new Class Library(Package) in C# gives me a seemingly broken reference list. Even old projects when opened show no references.

This started happening after installing Windows Management Framework 4 to resolve the error saying `The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details` as was recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549273/3547347 .

This only seems to happen with Class Library(Package) projects.

[image]

How can I fix this? I can't even add .NET references without browsing to their dll directly.

Edit: Add Reference Screen:
[image]

Comment: what do you see when you go to add reference section?

Comment: It just shows two categories to the left (Projects, Assemblies), and then where you can usually find your references "No items found".

Comment: looks dumb but have you tried restarting visual studio

Comment: It's not dumb, simplest fixes first. I've restarted it and my pc.

Comment: browse the path to GAC `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly`.try adding the assembly reference

Comment: This happens *because* you have an install problem with DNX.  The fix you tried did not solve the root problem.  After a proper install you should have a `C:\Users\yourname\.dnx\packages` subdirectory.

Comment: @HansPassant I do have that directory. The subfolders also seem to be populated. Shreesha, I cannot browse, if I try I get a warning saying "Project does not have target frameworks specified"