# The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dnx, .net-core, dnvm

In VS2015 running on Windows 10 x64 machine, I am getting below error while trying to build the `.net core` web project.

```
The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details
```

Here is the output window log (only relevant portion)

```
1>Done building target "BeforeCompile" in project "WebApplication1.xproj".
1>       Target "_TimeStampBeforeCompile" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(RunPostBuildEvent)'=='OnOutputUpdated' or ('$(RegisterForComInterop)'=='true' and '$(OutputType)'=='library')) was evaluated as (''=='OnOutputUpdated' or (''=='true' and 'Library'=='library')).
1>     1>
1>Target "GetRuntimeToolingPathTarget" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets" from project "C:\Users\v-prchep\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.xproj" (target "CoreCompile" depends on it):
1>       Using "GetRuntimeToolingPath" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Tasks.dll".
1>       Task "GetRuntimeToolingPath"
1>       Done executing task "GetRuntimeToolingPath".
1>       Using "Error" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>       Task "Error"
1>     1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets(126,5): error : The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details.
1>       Done executing task "Error" -- FAILED.
1>     1>
1>Done building target "GetRuntimeToolingPathTarget" in project "WebApplication1.xproj" -- FAILED.
1>     1>
1>Target "_CheckForCompileOutputs" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Users\v-prchep\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.xproj" (target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" depends on it):
1>     1>
1>Done building target "_CheckForCompileOutputs" in project "WebApplication1.xproj".
1>       Target "_SGenCheckForOutputs" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)' == 'On' or ('@(WebReferenceUrl)'!='' and '$(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)' == 'Auto')) was evaluated as ('Off' == 'On' or (''!='' and 'Off' == 'Auto')).
1>     1>
1>Target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Users\v-prchep\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.xproj" (target "_CleanRecordFileWrites" depends on it):
1>       Task "ReadLinesFromFile"
1>       Done executing task "ReadLinesFromFile".
1>       Using "ConvertToAbsolutePath" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>       Task "ConvertToAbsolutePath"
1>       Done executing task "ConvertToAbsolutePath".
1>       Task "FindUnderPath"
1>         Comparison path is "C:\Users\v-prchep\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1".
1>       Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
1>       Task "FindUnderPath"
1>         Comparison path is "..\..\artifacts\bin\WebApplication1\".
1>       Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
1>       Task "FindUnderPath"
1>         Comparison path is "..\..\artifacts\obj\WebApplication1\Debug\".
1>       Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
1>       Task "RemoveDuplicates"
1>       Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
1>     1>
1>Done building target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" in project "WebApplication1.xproj".
1>     1>
1>Target "_CleanRecordFileWrites" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Users\v-prchep\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.xproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
1>       Task "RemoveDuplicates"
1>       Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
1>       Task "MakeDir"
1>       Done executing task "MakeDir".
1>       Task "WriteLinesToFile"
1>       Done executing task "WriteLinesToFile".
1>     1>
1>Done building target "_CleanRecordFileWrites" in project "WebApplication1.xproj".
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.02
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Going behind the log, I checked `Microsoft.DNX.targets` file and found this line

```
<Error Text="The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details." Condition="!Exists('$(RuntimeToolingExe)')" />
```

Seems like it is trying to find-out the `dnx` path from `$(RuntimeToolingExe)` but I am not able to figure-out where it is being set.

**Note:** The `dnx` runtimes are already installed and I am able to run the application from command prompt using following command

```
dnx web
```

The application is running fine with this. I believe it is an issue with the VS2015 tooling which I am not able to figure-out. Could you please help me on this?

PS: Followed all the steps provided in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546274/how-to-fix-dnx-dnvm-in-visual-studio-2015) nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue finally resolved once I uninstall [styleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/). Seems like the StyleCop was overriding the `dnx` path which Visual Studio was looking for. However, this is just a guess, I am not particularly sure why it worked!

Comment: I have been having this same problem as well. I managed to track the issue down to Microsoft.DNX.targets. The RuntimeToolingDirectory should be set to the dnx path and use the version/runtime etc. in global.json to determine the correct runtime. e.g. "%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2" For some reason with stylecop installed it was just using the version name e.g. "1.0.0-rc1-update2". I've not the slightest clue why, but thank you so much for pointing me at stylecop. Would not have thought of that in a million years.

Comment: What I find strange is I only get this condition when I start an *Empty* project. If I select *Web API*, or *Web Application* (which are nearly the same, API has views??) then I get no such error, even with StyleCop installed. Busy installing StyleCop to see if I can get a working *Empty*. ReSharper's StyleCop extension suites me more as it's real time.

Comment: I meant, "Busy UNinstalling StyleCop...".  It didn't help. But in my `global.json` it only has the version name:

  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  } And, I wonder why I'm on `update1` after running update 2 for VS2015 yesterday.