# DNX design time error - System cannot find file specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

When i try to run the ASP NET 5 solution, i get below error.

Microsoft Visual Studio Error
The following error occurred attempting to run the DNX design time process (dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8).

The system cannot find the file specified.

The DNX design time process provides intellisense, build, and reference information to Visual Studio and without it your experience will be very limited. Please try closing and reopening Visual Studio to see if that corrects the problem. Alternatively, check that the DNX version is properly installed or try changing to a different installed DNX version using the project property pages.

Answer (score 0):

The project is not finding DNX SDK (if you look at the project properties you may see an empty drop-list next to 'Solution DNX SDK version').

If you are on windows 7, I suspect you may have an old version of powershell installed. You need at least version 3.0.

See this answer on a similar issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549273/299529